# Chrome does not make additional request for seeking video file

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, mp4

I try to achieve pseudo streaming, I have html like so:

```
<video src="GetVideo.ashx?id=mp4" controls></video>
```

after loading page Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m sends request (even before clicking play):

```
GET /GetVideo.ashx?id=mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/JWPlayerTestMp4Proper.aspx
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: jwplayer.volume=12
Range: bytes=0-
```

And server responds with

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 5186931
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 0-5186930/5186931
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2013 08:13:28 GMT
```

File starts to play after clicking play, but the problem is if i try to seek to yet not downloaded part, it does not send additional request for that part, it simply waits until file is downloaded upon specified position.

When I do the same in Firefox 22.0:
first request (after page loading):

```
GET http://localhost/GetVideo.ashx?id=mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Range: bytes=0-
Referer: http://localhost/JWPlayerTestMp4Proper.aspx
Connection: keep-alive
```

first response (it is the same as for Chrome):

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 5186931
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 0-5186930/5186931
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2013 08:28:19 GMT
```

second request (after seeking to yet not downloaded part):

```
GET http://localhost/GetVideo.ashx?id=mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Range: bytes=2490368-
Referer: http://localhost/JWPlayerTestMp4Proper.aspx
Connection: keep-alive
```

second response:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 2696563
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 2490368-5186930/5186931
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2013 08:35:34 GMT
```

IE 10 is working in the same way as Firefox.

What response header Chrome expects to be able to behave in the same way - to make addtional requests after seeking to not-downloaded part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out response header was correct.
The problem was I was using video file with small length and chrome appears to have some kind  of optimization not sending additional request if difference in time is too small (less then 30 seconds or so).